# The system can't upgrade raspbian and there are errors

Tags: update

As the title saying, I don't know how to resolve this matter. Here I publish  the notification. Hope someone know how to resolve it. I have skipped the "GET" list if not it has many rows.

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 149028 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libavutil54_6%3a11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libavutil54:armhf (6:11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1) over (6:11.7-1~deb8u1+rpi1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libavresample2_6%3a11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libavresample2:armhf (6:11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1) over (6:11.1~deb8u1+rpi1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libavcodec56_6%3a11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libavcodec56:armhf (6:11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1) over (6:11.7-1~deb8u1+rpi1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libavformat56_6%3a11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libavformat56:armhf (6:11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1) over (6:11.7-1~deb8u1+rpi1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgd3_2.1.0-5+deb8u7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgd3:armhf (2.1.0-5+deb8u7) over (2.1.0-5+deb8u6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../liblightdm-gobject-1-0_1.10.3-3+rpi_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking liblightdm-gobject-1-0 (1.10.3-3+rpi) over (1.10.3-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libnspr4_2%3a4.12-1+debu8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libnspr4:armhf (2:4.12-1+debu8u1) over (2:4.10.7-1+deb8u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libnss3_2%3a3.26-1+debu8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libnss3:armhf (2:3.26-1+debu8u1) over (2:3.17.2-1.1+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../uno-libs3_4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking uno-libs3 (4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../ure_4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking ure (4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-calc_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-calc (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-impress_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-impress (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-draw_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-draw (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-gtk_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-gtk (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-writer_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-writer (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python3-uno_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python3-uno (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-base-core_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-base-core (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-math_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-math (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/libreoffice/share/template/common/wizard/report/cnt-01.ott' to '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/template/common/wizard/report/cnt-01.ott.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/program/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-base_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-base (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-base_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/libreoffice-base/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/libreoffice-base/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of libreoffice-base, which would be broken by installation of libreoffice-core ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure libreoffice-base (broken by libreoffice-core)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-core_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
De-configuring libreoffice-base (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
Unpacking libreoffice-core (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-core_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/libreoffice-core/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/libreoffice-core/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-base-drivers_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-base-drivers (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-base-drivers_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/libreoffice-base-drivers/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/libreoffice-base-drivers/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../fonts-opensymbol_2%3a102.6+LibO4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-opensymbol (2:102.6+LibO4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (2:102.6+LibO4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-opensymbol_2%3a102.6+LibO4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/fonts-opensymbol/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/fonts-opensymbol/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-report-builder-bin_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-report-builder-bin (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-report-builder-bin_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/libreoffice-report-builder-bin/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/libreoffice-report-builder-bin/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-java-common_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-java-common (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-java-common_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/java/unoil-4.3.3.jar' to '/usr/share/java/unoil-4.3.3.jar.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-style-galaxy_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-style-galaxy (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-style-galaxy_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/images.zip' to '/usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/images.zip.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libswscale3_6%3a11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libswscale3:armhf (6:11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1) over (6:11.7-1~deb8u1+rpi1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libswscale3_6%3a11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp/libswscale.so.3.0.0' to '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp/libswscale.so.3.0.0.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libc-ares2_1.10.0-2+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libc-ares2:armhf (1.10.0-2+deb8u1) over (1.10.0-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../ghostscript_9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking ghostscript (9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3) over (9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ghostscript_9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/ghostscript/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/ghostscript/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libgs9_9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgs9 (9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3) over (9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgs9_9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/libgs9/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/libgs9/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libgs9-common_9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgs9-common (9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3) over (9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgs9-common_9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/libgs9-common/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/libgs9-common/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../php5-gd_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking php5-gd (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../php5-readline_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking php5-readline (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../php5-cli_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking php5-cli (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-cli_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/bin/php5' to '/usr/bin/php5.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../php5-mcrypt_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking php5-mcrypt (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../php5-curl_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking php5-curl (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../php5-mysql_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking php5-mysql (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-mysql_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqli.so' to '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqli.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-php5_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php5 (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libapache2-mod-php5_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so' to '/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../php5-common_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking php5-common (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-common_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/php5/20131226/opcache.so' to '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/opcache.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.028-2+deb8u2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (4.028-2+deb8u2) over (4.028-2+deb8u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbd-mysql-perl_4.028-2+deb8u2_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.20/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' to '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.20/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb (1:4.3.3-2+rpi4) over (1:4.3.3-2+rpi3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb/changelog.Debian.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb/changelog.Debian.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../lightdm_1.10.3-3+rpi_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking lightdm (1.10.3-3+rpi) over (1.10.3-3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/lightdm_1.10.3-3+rpi_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/sbin/lightdm' to '/usr/sbin/lightdm.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../lxpanel_0.7.2-1+rpi13_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking lxpanel (0.7.2-1+rpi13) over (0.7.2-1+rpi12) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/lxpanel_0.7.2-1+rpi13_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxpanel/plugins/cpu.so' to '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxpanel/plugins/cpu.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../lxpanel-data_0.7.2-1+rpi13_all.deb ...
Unpacking lxpanel-data (0.7.2-1+rpi13) over (0.7.2-1+rpi12) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/lxpanel-data_0.7.2-1+rpi13_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/lxpanel.mo' to '/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/lxpanel.mo.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../nuscratch_20160915+1_armhf.deb ...
Leaving 'diversion of /usr/bin/scratch to /usr/bin/scratch.old by nuscratch'
Leaving 'diversion of /usr/bin/squeak to /usr/bin/squeak.old by nuscratch'
Leaving 'diversion of /usr/share/scratch/locale/ja_HIRA.po to /usr/share/scratch/locale/ja_HIRA.po.old by nuscratch'
Leaving 'diversion of /usr/share/scratch/locale/ja.po to /usr/share/scratch/locale/ja.po.old by nuscratch'
Unpacking nuscratch (20160915+1) over (20160915) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nuscratch_20160915+1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/squeak/5.0-201608180858/squeak' to '/usr/lib/squeak/5.0-201608180858/squeak.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../php-pear_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-pear (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/php-pear_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/php/.registry/pear.reg' to '/usr/share/php/.registry/pear.reg.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../php5_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php5 (5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1) over (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../pi-greeter_0.3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking pi-greeter (0.3) over (0.1-2) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pi-greeter_0.3_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../pipanel_20161012~175500_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking pipanel (20161012~175500) over (20160719~175800) ...
Preparing to unpack .../pishutdown_0.7_armhf.deb ...
Leaving 'diversion of /usr/bin/lxde-pi-shutdown-helper to /usr/bin/lxde-pi-shutdown-helper.old by pishutdown'
Unpacking pishutdown (0.7) over (0.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../archives/pix-icons_0.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking pix-icons (0.3) over (0.1-1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pix-icons_0.3_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/icons/PiX/16x16/categories/preferences-desktop.png' to '/usr/share/icons/PiX/16x16/categories/preferences-desktop.png.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../pix-plym-splash_0.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking pix-plym-splash (0.3) over (0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../pixel-wallpaper_0.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking pixel-wallpaper (0.2) over (0.1-1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pixel-wallpaper_0.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/pixel-wallpaper/aurora.jpg' to '/usr/share/pixel-wallpaper/aurora.jpg.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../raspberrypi-sys-mods_20161010_all.deb ...
Unpacking raspberrypi-sys-mods (20161010) over (20160916) ...
Preparing to unpack .../raspi-config_20161013_all.deb ...
Unpacking raspi-config (20161013) over (20160810) ...
Preparing to unpack .../archives/rc-gui_1.2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking rc-gui (1.2) over (1.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../archives/bluej_3.1.7a_all.deb ...
Unpacking bluej (3.1.7a) over (3.1.7) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/bluej_3.1.7a_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/bluej/afrikaans/labels' to '/usr/share/bluej/afrikaans/labels.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Preparing to unpack .../raspberrypi-net-mods_1.2.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking raspberrypi-net-mods (1.2.4) over (1.2.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php5 (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.20-0+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-base_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-core_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-base-drivers_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-opensymbol_2%3a102.6+LibO4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-report-builder-bin_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-java-common_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-style-galaxy_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libswscale3_6%3a11.8-1~deb8u1+rpi1_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ghostscript_9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgs9_9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgs9-common_9.06~dfsg-2+deb8u3_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-cli_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-mysql_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libapache2-mod-php5_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-common_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbd-mysql-perl_4.028-2+deb8u2_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb_1%3a4.3.3-2+rpi4_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/lightdm_1.10.3-3+rpi_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/lxpanel_0.7.2-1+rpi13_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/lxpanel-data_0.7.2-1+rpi13_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nuscratch_20160915+1_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/php-pear_5.6.26+dfsg-0+deb8u1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pi-greeter_0.3_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pix-icons_0.3_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pixel-wallpaper_0.2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bluej_3.1.7a_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking either the package(s) download(s) might have failed midway resulting in *corrupted* files or the disk might have become full and file write might have failed. either way you can try the following steps
and see if it works

Try

- clearing the apt download cache with `sudo apt-get autoclean`
- removing obsolete packages no longer required `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- verify you have ample free disk space with `df -h`.
- re-run the upgrade command : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

if you have sufficient disk space and errors recur, it might warrant further investigation

Reference

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239822/unexpected-end-of-file-or-stream

Comment: Hello, this method isn't work. I refer to the other article.

Comment: http://yampblog.blogspot.tw/2015/09/solved-lzma-error-cannot-allocate-memory.html

Comment: I didn't try this article yet. There are different description. My pi has a unique  property. I separate the boot partition and the kernel partition. The kernel partition is plugged on the usb slot. Sorry for that I didn't mention first.